Monitor not working if i not go in UEFI or Grub
I got strange issue with laptop and fresh installed Mate Ubuntu 24.04.
If I boot without visiting GRUB or UEFI my display stays blank.
Other displays(via hub or directly via HDMI) are also blank.
Via ssh i can login in laptop but i'm not really see any errors.
If I

access UEFI via F12, change no settings and resume boot
or open GRUB via Esc, continue normal boot

I getting my login window.
And can use my laptop as usual with all displays(main laptop display, via hub and via HDMI).
I don't know if it happens with LiveUSB cause LiveUSB shows Grub menu on start.
I'm pretty sure that it is not X11 issue, cause i'm not getting default loading login with running dots under Mate Ubuntu logo.
And this loading screen is invoked before starting display server.
I mean this running dots
UPD
I found other workaround for this issue.
I removed in /etc/default/grub quet splash option:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

Now my Ubuntu boots in login screen without problems.
Specks:

Dell Inspiron 7440
CPU: Core Ultra 7 155H
GPU: Intel Ark(integrated)
Mate Ubuntu 24.04
X11 session.

